# Adding pixelData to pydicom dataset causes VR Error

Tags: python, pydicom

I am working with a set of dicom images. I would like to create a new image with a header similar to an existing image. However, I already propagate the images in numpy arrays, so to avoid duplication I propagate the headers without PixelData:

```
metadata = pydicom.filereader.dcmread(image_path[l],stop_before_pixels=True)
```

In a separate function, I want to attach a different image (an ROI) to the modified metadata:

```
ds = metadata
ds.PixelData = roi.astype(np.int16).tostring() # A numpy array converted to the same datatype as pixel_array was
ds.save_as(os.path.join(write_dir,'ROI'+str(slice+1))+'.dcm')
```

This results in an error message below which seems to indicate that the PixelData VR is not set in the dictionary? Thanks for your suggestions.

> ValueError: Cannot write ambiguous VR of 'OB or OW' for data element
>   with tag (7fe0, 0010). Set the correct VR before writing, or use an
>   implicit VR transfer syntax

Answer (score 6):

The VR for *Pixel Data* is [ambiguous in the DICOM Standard](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part05/sect_8.2.html). Depending on the exact nature of your dataset the required VR is either **OB** *or* **OW**. Because you're adding a brand new *Pixel Data* element to an existing dataset *pydicom* defaults the VR to `'OB or OW'`. Normally this isn't an issue *if* your dataset is conformant because during write *pydicom* will automatically fix this so the correct VR is used (using the [correct_ambiguous_vr()](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/reference/generated/pydicom.filewriter.correct_ambiguous_vr.html#pydicom.filewriter.correct_ambiguous_vr) function). If your dataset isn't conformant then:

- If your *Pixel Data* uses a compressed transfer syntax, like JPEG, then it should be **OB**.
- Otherwise, it should be **OB** if *Bits Allocated* <= 8 and **OW** if > 8.

```py
# Set the VR manually
ds['PixelData'].VR = 'OW'
```